# Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher - JAVA -SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher - JAVA -SpringBoot Application;

The application was working fine until a few months ago; is running fine locally but not the UNIX servers.

CLI used -

```
java -cp SomeJAR.jar -Dloader.main=MainClass org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher classpath:some.xml
```

The only that has changed in the project is that Unit Test Cases were added, what could be causing this issue???

Comment: have you changed/installed java's new version in UNIX server?

Comment: Highly unlikely...No

Comment: The dependency have not changed as well